# postgresql drop unique constraint after changing the class definition in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I had created a table model class in django:

```
class A(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Later after adding data, I changed the model definition to remove the unique constraint as

```
class A(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

In postgresql using psql I dropped the constraint as:

## alter table A drop constraint "unique_a_code_key";

Now after 2 days, still I am not able to add existing code value thru' django admin form. How can I remove the constraint  as i do not see it with #d+ A; in postgres

Comment: Probably a stupid question but did you reload the app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1414837/beltiras Have reloaded the app, its working fine. Though it is not all that stupid. The problem is the app was started in a screen few days back. But even after stopping the application in the screen and restarting, it shows that it is already running in that port. So I killed the process and restarted the application. Well! now it is working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have reloaded the django app, its working fine. The problem is the app was started in a screen few days back. But even after stopping the application in the screen and restarting, it shows that it is already running in that port. So I killed the process and restarted the application. Well! now it is working fine!